# check if time falls between a range not working

Tags: vba, excel, datetime

I need to check if time falls between 3:31:00 PM and 6:29:00 AM

This is what returns in Immediate window when I debug.

```
?TimeValue(TEMP.Cells(i, tAssgnStart)) >= WorksheetFunction.Min(TimeValue("15:31:00"), TimeValue("06:29:00"))
False
?TimeValue(TEMP.Cells(i, tAssgnStart))
02:00:00 
?WorksheetFunction.Min(TimeValue("15:31:00"), TimeValue("06:29:00"))
 0.270138888888889 
?cdate(WorksheetFunction.Min(TimeValue("15:31:00"), TimeValue("06:29:00")))
06:29:00 

?TimeValue(TEMP.Cells(i, tAssgnStart)) <= WorksheetFunction.Max(TimeValue("15:31:00"), TimeValue("06:29:00"))
True
?TimeValue(TEMP.Cells(i, tAssgnStart))
02:00:00 
?WorksheetFunction.Max(TimeValue("15:31:00"), TimeValue("06:29:00"))
 0.646527777777778 
?cdate(WorksheetFunction.Max(TimeValue("15:31:00"), TimeValue("06:29:00")))
15:31:00
```

I tried a lot of stuff but I can't get it right for some reason.
Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim t, x
    For x = 1 To 23
        t = TimeValue(Format(x, "00") & ":00:00")
        Debug.Print Format(t, "hh:mm:ss"), t > TimeValue("15:31:00") Or _
                                           t < TimeValue("06:29:00")
    Next x

End Sub
```

Output:

```
01:00:00      True
02:00:00      True
03:00:00      True
04:00:00      True
05:00:00      True
06:00:00      True
07:00:00      False
08:00:00      False
09:00:00      False
10:00:00      False
11:00:00      False
12:00:00      False
13:00:00      False
14:00:00      False
15:00:00      False
16:00:00      True
17:00:00      True
18:00:00      True
19:00:00      True
20:00:00      True
21:00:00      True
22:00:00      True
23:00:00      True
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is conceptually wrong. In Excel (VBA), one day is an integer. Debug.Print CLng(Date) will give you today's integer. Tomorrow will be today + 1. Today started at 00:00 hours and will end at 24:00 hours. Therefore every hour equals 1/24, every minute 1/24/60, every second 1/24/60/60 and so on. Time is a Double value and can be very exact. More roughly speaking, 43028.5 is a Date/Time value representing 12 noon on October 20, 2017.

Obviously 15:31 (0.646527777777778 ) is later than 06:29 (0.270138888888889). If you wish to specify tomorrow's 06:29 you will have to add a day, for example 1.270138888888889 or 43029.270138888888889. To determine if a time is between 43028.646527777777778 and 43029.270138888888889 will not pose a problem for you, or will it?

Debug.Print CDbl(Now) will give you the Date/Time value for the current date and time. Cdbl(TimeValue("15:31")) will return the time value as a fraction of 1.

Answer (score 0):

Variatus gives a good overview of how time and date values are stored in Excel. In order to compare just the time-values of some arbitrary values, I'd do something like the below, where subtracting the integer-parts of the values you use will make it certain that just the time-part of the variables are compared.

```
Function isBetweenTimes(fromTime As Date, toTime As Date, timeToCheck As Date) As Boolean
  Dim f As Double, t As Double, c As Double

  f = CDbl(fromTime): f = f - Int(f)
  t = CDbl(toTime): t = t - Int(t)
  c = CDbl(timeToCheck): c = c - Int(c)

  isBetweenTimes = CBool(c >= f And c <= t)
End Function

Sub testFunction()
  Dim fromTime As Date, toTime As Date, timeToCheck As Date

  fromTime = #6:29:00 AM#
  toTime = #3:31:00 PM#
  timeToCheck = #2:00:00 PM#

  Debug.Print isBetweenTimes(fromTime, toTime, timeToCheck)
End Sub
```

If you also care about what dates the values are on, you obviously don't need to do the subtraction.

Comment: But this seems a little to much effort to be honest. is there anything wrong with Tim's Answer?

Comment: @Rohan Well, I don't like dealing with dates as strings, which is what `timevalue` does. If you deal with them as actual date-values, you'll have fewer chances of e.g. formatting causing problems. Furthermore, his approach only shows a bunch of code, which goes against the principles of stackoverflow - to be fair, the question wasn't that complicated but I still feel that at least a simple explanation of why you do what you do in your answer is in order.

Comment: @Rohan The function showed in this answer can also be plugged into whatever future macros you want to use it in, and is pretty self-descriptive in what it does - reading the code in Tim's answer isn't quite as easy. There are also some minor nitpicks I have about him not declaring the types of his variables and suchlike, but these are more about good coding standards than anything else :P